# How to create ODBC DSN 64bit using c# code

Tags: c#

I used below code to create ODBC DSN. It ran successful and creeated ODBC DSN 32bit. However, I need to create ODBC DSN 64 bit. Do you know any change in below code to make it happen?

Thanks,

```
//////////////
using Microsoft.Win32;
//////////////

string ODBC_PATH = "SOFTWARE\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI\\";
string driverName = "SQL Server Native Client 11.0";
string dsnName = "DSNfromCode";
string database = "MYDBNAME";
string description = "This DSN was created from code!";
string server = ".";
bool trustedConnection = true;

// Lookup driver path from driver name         
string driverPath = "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\sqlncli11.dll";

var datasourcesKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(ODBC_PATH + "ODBC Data Sources");
if (datasourcesKey == null)
{
    throw new Exception("ODBC Registry key does not exist");
}
datasourcesKey.SetValue(dsnName, driverName);
// Create new key in odbc.ini with dsn name and add values        
var dsnKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(ODBC_PATH + dsnName);
if (dsnKey == null)
{
    throw new Exception("ODBC Registry key for DSN was not created");
}

dsnKey.SetValue("Database", database);
dsnKey.SetValue("Description", description);
dsnKey.SetValue("Driver", driverPath);
dsnKey.SetValue("LastUser", "sa");
dsnKey.SetValue("Server", server);
dsnKey.SetValue("Database", database);
dsnKey.SetValue("username", "sa");
dsnKey.SetValue("password", "system123#");
dsnKey.SetValue("Trusted_Connection", trustedConnection ? "Yes" : "No");
```

Comment: Improved code formatting

Answer (score 0):

based on https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942976 I have a gut feeling that the system DSN for 64 bit will be placed in the same registry folder. So based on the assumption you just need to modify your driverPath variable for 64bit case.

Another approact would be create on x64 machine your DSN using 64-bit ODBC Administrator tool. Find the DSN in registry, check what is there and implement the same in C#.

Some recommendation for the future... please review the code you post. especially when it goes in sa user password :)